# standard rock-paper-scissors code in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
player1 = raw_input("Player 1? ")
player2 = raw_input("Player 2? ")

if ((player1 != "rock" or
    player1 != "paper" or
    player1 != "scissors") and
    (player2 != "rock" or
    player2 != "paper" or
    player2 != "scissors")):
    if (player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'rock'):
        print 'Tie.'
    if (player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'paper'):
        print 'Tie.'
    if (player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'scissors'):
        print 'Tie.'
    if (player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'rock'):
        print 'Player 1 wins.'
    if (player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'scissors'):
        print 'Player 1 wins.'
    if (player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'paper'):
        print 'Player 1 wins.'
    if (player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'paper'):
        print 'Player 2 wins.'
    if (player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'rock'):
        print 'Player 2 wins.'
    if (player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'scissors'):
        print 'Player 2 wins.'
else:
    print "This is not a valid object selection."
```

above is the code, for some reason, the else statement never prints, when you enter something not rock, paper, or scissors. can someone help me with this?

Comment: Shouldn't the comparisons up top be equality? e.g. if (( player1 == "rock" or player1 == "paper" ...

Comment: You need to change all your `!=` to an `==`

Comment: If you have `!= rock`, how would `== rock` ever be true?

Comment: thanks for the feedback! i forgot that swapped if and else statements....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditionals `!=` needs to be changed to `==`

```
player1 = raw_input("Player 1? ")
player2 = raw_input("Player 2? ")

if ((player1 == "rock" or
    player1 == "paper" or
    player1 == "scissors") and
    (player2 == "rock" or
    player2 == "paper" or
    player2 == "scissors")):
    if (player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'rock'):
        print 'Tie.'
    if (player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'paper'):
        print 'Tie.'
    if (player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'scissors'):
        print 'Tie.'
    if (player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'rock'):
        print 'Player 1 wins.'
    if (player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'scissors'):
        print 'Player 1 wins.'
    if (player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'paper'):
        print 'Player 1 wins.'
    if (player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'paper'):
        print 'Player 2 wins.'
    if (player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'rock'):
        print 'Player 2 wins.'
    if (player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'scissors'):
        print 'Player 2 wins.'
else:
    print "This is not a valid object selection."
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first `if` statement will always evaluate to `true`. Replace `!=` with `==` and you will be happy.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `in`.

```
player1 = raw_input("Player 1? ")
player2 = raw_input("Player 2? ")

valid_opts = {'rock', 'paper', 'scissors'}
if player1.lower() in valid_opts and player2.lower() in valid_opts:
    ...
else:
    print("invalid input")
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out by others, you need to change several `!=` to `==`. You might also consider some shortening:

```
if len(set(player1, player2, "rock", "paper", "scissors")) == 3:
    if player1 == player2:
        print 'Tie.'
    answers = ["Player 1 wins.", "Player 2 wins."]
    elif player1 == "rock":
        print answers[player2=="paper"]
    elif player1 == "paper":
        print answers[player2=="scissors"]
    elif player1 == "scissors":
        print answers[player2=="rock"]
else:
    print "This is not a valid object selection."
```

Comment: If you're going with this method you might want to update `player1` and `player2` so that they the string will be lowercased
`player1 = str(raw_input("Player 1? ")).lower()`
`player2 = str(raw_input("Player 2? ")).lower()`

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your entire program with a `dict` and a series of `if/elif/else` statements:

```
priority = dict(rock='scissors', paper='rock', scissors='paper')

player_1 = raw_input('Player 1? ')
player_2 = raw_input('Player 2? ')

if player_1 not in priority or player_2 not in priority:
    print 'This is not a valid object selection.'
elif player_1 == player_2:
    print 'Tie.'
elif priority[player_1] == player_2:
    print 'Player 1 wins.'
else:
    print 'Player 2 wins.'
```

With just a little work, you can have the code accommodate the rules for [RPSSL](http://www.samkass.com/theories/RPSSL.html) if you want:

```
priority = dict(scissors={'paper', 'lizard'},
                paper={'rock', 'spock'},
                rock={'lizard', 'scissors'},
                lizard={'spock', 'paper'},
                spock={'scissors', 'rock'})

player_1 = raw_input('Player 1? ')
player_2 = raw_input('Player 2? ')

if player_1 not in priority or player_2 not in priority:
    print 'This is not a valid object selection.'
elif player_1 == player_2:
    print 'Tie.'
elif player_2 in priority[player_1]:
    print 'Player 1 wins.'
else:
    print 'Player 2 wins.'
```